# SQL Server 2008 R2 Inner Join Fails to match varchar fields because it contains special characters

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, inner-join, keyword

We are using Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 for one of our Classic ASP applications.

We have two tables:

- TableA
- TableB

`TableA` has the following columns:

- `InstName(varchar[1024])`

`TableB` has these columns:

- `InstitutionName(varchar[1024])`

However, we came across some data like the following

**TableA**

`InstName` with value University of Nantes [ Universites de Nantes ]

**TableB**

`InstitutionName` with value University of Nantes [ Universites de Nantes ]

We need to run inner join select queries on the said 2 tables:

```
select *
from TableA
inner join TableB on TableA.InstName LIKE TableB.InstitutionName
```

Sadly, this inner join fails to match the columns with the value of University of Nantes [ Universites de Nantes ]

I do know that "[]" square brackets have special meaning in Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2.

Please modify the said inner join select query in such a way that it escapes the "[]" square brackets so that the match is found, and paste the said modified query on this stackoverflow.com ticket.

Furthermore, please advise on how I should deal with other special characters like "[]" square brackets that have special meaning in Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to `JOIN` on two fields using `LIKE` that contain `[`, you'll need to escape the opening bracket since the bracket is a wildcard character.  For any wildcard characters, you can use brackets `[]` - this will search for any single character within the specified range.

For example, this should work in your scenario using `REPLACE`:

```
select * 
from yourtable t inner join 
    yourtable2 t2 on t.field like replace(t2.field,'[', '[[]')
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/266fb/1)

Alternatively, for your sample data, you have no reason to use `LIKE` as `=` would work the same.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  Are there any other special keyword characters considered by Microsoft SQL Server other than the square brackets that would require replacement?

Comment: @user1338998 -- this should help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859(v=sql.100).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Use `=` instead of `LIKE`.

Your query should read:

```
select *
     from TableA
     inner join TableB
     on TableA.InstName = TableB.InstitutionName
```

I confirmed with the following:

```
declare @t1 table(name varchar(1024))
insert into @t1(name) values('[ Universites de Nantes ]');

declare @t2 table(name varchar(1024))
insert into @t2(name) values('[ Universites de Nantes ]');

--nothing returned
    select * from @t1 t1
    inner join @t2 t2 ON t2.name LIKE t1.name

--one record returned
    select * from @t1 t1
    inner join @t2 t2 ON t2.name = t1.name
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Are there any other special keyword characters considered by Microsoft SQL Server other than the square brackets that would require replacement?

Comment: Well, I would take a step back and say that if you're doing an inner join you shouldn't be using the 'LIKE' operator.  If you are in fact using wildcards ('%') then I would do an inner select in the where clause...it reads much better and communicates what you're doing.

In your case, it looks like you truly want an exact match too.  

To answer your question, '%' will act as a wild card...so when using LIKE, '%Universites' will match with 'Universites'.  It is possible that some place has that in their name complicating factors.

In summary: use '=' for joins, and 'LIKE' for predicates.